# How to determine if a word is found in a column and if it is not how do I make sure that it shows in dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I want it to count each instance a word comes up but the problem I have is this particular data set does not include other Status' like Backlog, On hold etc. and I want the new DataFrame to include these so using the above example it should look like:

Is there any way to put through a filter so it search for all these instances, counts them and then makes a new table like the second one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CategoricalDtype` that way the default behavior is to show the counts for all classes.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Status': ['done', 'done', 'not a problem', 'done', 'not a problem']})
```

---

```
my_cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(['done', 'not a problem', 'backlog', 'on hold', 'implement'])
df['Status'] = df['Status'].astype(my_cat)

df['Status'].value_counts()
#done             3
#not a problem    2
#backlog          0
#on hold          0
#implement        0
#Name: Status, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can you `value_counts`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Status": ["done", "done", "not a problem", "done", "not a problem"]})
statuses = ["done", "not a problem", "backlog", "on hold", "implement"]

>>> df["Status"].value_counts().reindex(statuses, fill_value=0)
done             3
not a problem    2
backlog          0
on hold          0
implement        0
Name: Status, dtype: int64
```